# Docker container mongodb with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize my API, but when I start the application with docker-compose file, the mongodb doesn't starts, and the application cannot connect to the database. By running the application tests using docker, the tests run correctly, but when running npm run production, the mongodb service starts and deactivates.

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: 
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.production 
      args:
        port: ${PORT}
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: database:27017
  database:
    image: mongo:latest
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    volumes:
      - ".${MONGO_DATA_DIR}:${MONGO_DATA_DIR}"
    expose:
      - 27017
    command: "mongod --smallfiles --logpath=${MONGO_LOG_FILE}"
```

***docker-compose.test.yml***

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend-test:
    build: 
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.test
      args:
        port: ${PORT}
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: database-test:27017
  database-test:
    image: mongo:latest
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    volumes:
      - ".${MONGO_TEST_DATA_DIR}:${MONGO_TEST_DATA_DIR}"
    expose:
      - 27017
    command: "mongod --smallfiles --logpath=${MONGO_LOG_FILE}"
```

***Dockerfile.production***

```
FROM node:10.12.0-alpine
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.2.1/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
WORKDIR /home/nodejs/app
ENV NODE_ENV prod
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
ARG port=80
EXPOSE $port
COPY . ./
CMD /wait && node index.js
```

***Dockerfile.test***

```
FROM docker_backend
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.2.1/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
ENV NODE_ENV dev
RUN npm install && npm install -g mocha --timeout 10000
ARG port=80
CMD /wait && mocha tests/unitTests.js --exit
```

***index.js***

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient = require('mongodb')

const dbName = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? 'database-test' : 'database'
const url = `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}@${dbName}:27017?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=admin`
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    reconnectTries: 60, 
    reconnectInterval: 1000
}
const user = require('./routes/user.js')
const port = process.env.PORT || 80
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app)

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.use('/api/v1', user)
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404)
})

MongoClient.connect(url, options, (err, database) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(`FATAL MONGODB CONNECTION ERROR: $(err):$(err.stack)`)
        process.exit(1)
    }
    app.locals.db = database.db('api')
    http.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Listening on port " + port)
        app.emit('APP_STARTED')
    })
})

module.exports = app
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "user-register-backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A api to register users backend using cpf and cnpj validation",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.test.yml up --build --abort-on-container-exit",
    "production": "docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up",
    "build": "docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml build"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "express",
    "mongo"
  ],
  "author": "Jefferson Bruchado",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0",
    "tape": "^4.9.1"
  }
}
```

Running npm run test, the application works and performs the unit tests, but when I try to run npm run production, the mongodb service does not start, therefore the application does not work.

***Error:***

```
> docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up

Starting docker_database_1 ... done
Starting docker_backend_1  ... done
Attaching to docker_backend_1, docker_database_1
backend_1   | Checking availability of database:27017
backend_1   | Host database:27017 not yet available
database_1  | about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
database_1  | forked process: 24
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.914+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.918+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=24 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=f1619d77c7b7
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.5
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.922+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017, ssl: { mode: "disabled" } }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/tmp/docker-entrypoint-temp-mongod.pid" }, storage: { mmapv1: { smallFiles: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/proc/1/fd/1" } }
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:25.948+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=478M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
backend_1   | Host database:27017 not yet available
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.837+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1546104506:837236][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1546104506:837236][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.892+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1546104506:892012][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1546104506:892012][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.895+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.1
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.898+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1546104506:898402][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1546104506:898402][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.967+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1546104506:967112][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1546104506:967112][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.970+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.2
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.972+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (1) [1546104506:972043][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted Raw: [1546104506:972043][24:0x7f5c86498a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: Operation not permitted
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.974+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.974+0000 F STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.974+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 638
database_1  | 2018-12-29T17:28:26.974+0000 F -        [initandlisten]
database_1  |
database_1  | ***aborting after fassert() failure
database_1  |
database_1  |
database_1  | ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14
database_1  | To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
docker_database_1 exited with code 14
backend_1   | Host database:27017 not yet available
backend_1   | Host database:27017 not yet available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be that when the server starts, the db is not created yet. You need a script to ensure the server only starts after the database is created.

To more information you have this link https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Or a repo that I created with that problem https://github.com/PedroS11/node-postgres-redis-docker